# tsql LTRIM and LEN with leading and trailing spaces

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My string contains leading and trailing spaces (see below).

When I applied the LRTIM function it appears to work. Next, when I nest the LTRIM function with the LEN function to the string, it appears the length is off by 1 (i.e. length of original string is 16, LTRIM removed the single (1) leading space from the string, so I expected LEN to return a length of 15, not 14).  Any explanations?

```
SELECT
 ' This is a test ' AS origStr
,LEN(' This is a test ') AS origStrLen
,'[' + LTRIM(' This is a test ') + ']' AS ltrimStr
,LEN(LTRIM(' This is a test ')) AS strLtrimLen
;
```

Results:

```
This is a test | 16 | [This is a test ] | 14 |
```

Comment: Sorry for the re-posted of this specific question. And thanks for providing the link that explains this issue. I read up on DATALENGTH vs LEN.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the len() not counting after string space.

```
LEN(LTRIM(' This is a test ')) has one space before and one space after string.
```

Example:
`SELECT LEN('TEXT ')` RETURNS---> 4